# Check for null and substitute by 0

Tags: scala

I have the following statement which gets data from Redis DB using `client`. For some entries it returns `null`. How can I check for `null` and substitute it by `0` in a single line? Is there something similar to `getOrElse`? Or maybe I can somehow use `Option[String]`? I want to avoid using `if qty_str == null`.

```
val qty_str : String = Dress.up(client).hget("pk:"+ind,"qty")
```

Comment: I would go for `getOrElse` on `Option[String]`

Comment: I've used `hincrby field_name 0`, it effectively does what you want... :)

Comment: @sebszyller: Yes, but how to apply it in this particular case? This approach does not compile: `al qty_str : Option[String] = Dress.up(client).hget("pk:"+ind,"qty").getOrElse(??)`

Comment: @Lobsterrrr, what library are you using? Maybe it returns a `Future[Option[String]]`?

Comment: @insan-e: I am using this one `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.sedis</groupId>
            <artifactId>sedis_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Option` function turns a `T` which might be null into an `Option[T]`. Once you have that, you can use `map` to turn your `Option[String]` to an `Option[Int]`, followed by `getOrElse` to replace `None` with your default value.

```
val qty_not_null : Option[String] = Option(qty_str)
val qty_int : Int = qty_not_null.map(_.toInt).getOrElse(0)
```